# How to connect BLTouch sensor to Alunar M508 using LSEE 3D v1.0 board?

Tags: prusa-i3, marlin, bed-leveling, bltouch, alunar-m508

In the process of updating my printer (Alunar M508), I decided to add "Auto Bed Leveling" using a BLTouch sensor. After doing a lot of Googling:

1. [I found firmware](https://github.com/skryshtafovych/alunar-prusa-i3-marlin-i3-firmware) that will upload and work with printer in default configuration (without BLTouch)
2. Adding BLTouch configuration, the software compiles and updates the printer, I see all new options in menu and BLTouch on "power on" does a self test.

I know I have configured the power to the device correctly 2 power sources and ground but where I'm having issues is in identifying `Servo0` and `ZMax/Min` on my board. So far the black and white wire are connected to Z axis "end stop" but I cannot identify where to connect the orange signal wire to. I cannot find pinout anywhere of this board.
[image: LSEE 3D v1.0 board and peripherals]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LSEE 3D is basically a [RAMPS board](http://greatprinterstore.blogspot.com/2016/10/cheap-lsee-3d-v10-version-mainboard.html) (your linked source also shows that the used `MOTHERBOARD` is a RAMPS board: `#define MOTHERBOARD BOARD_RAMPS_14_EFB`), this implies that all pins of your board are the same as a RAMPS board. To connect the 3 pin header of the BLTouch sensor you need to connect the red wire to +5 V and the black wire to ground; the orange wire needs to be connected to an available PWM pin. As the LSEE board does not have many exposed (free) pins for you to use, you need to re-use one of the existing PWM pins that you do not use. An example is the pin nr. 2. From the [pins_RAMPS.h file](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/pins_RAMPS.h) you see in the limit switches section:

```
//
// Limit Switches
//
#define X_MIN_PIN           3
#ifndef X_MAX_PIN
  #define X_MAX_PIN         2
#endif
```

It appears, from the image, that your board does have max limit end stop switches header pins available. What you could do is use the `X_MAX_PIN` for the BLTouch sensor.

This implies that you need to assign the servo pin to pin nr. 2.

From the servos section of the same [pins_RAMPS.h file](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/pins_RAMPS.h) you see that the servos are either connected to pin 7 or pin 11 (depending on the board, your linked sources use the 1.4 version).

```
//
// Servos
//
#ifdef IS_RAMPS_13
  #define SERVO0_PIN        7   // RAMPS_13 // Will conflict with BTN_EN2 on LCD_I2C_VIKI
#else
  #define SERVO0_PIN       11
#endif
```

Using the linked sources, the 11 should be replaced with a 2. This implies that you can connect the orange wire to the "signal" pin of the X_MAX end stop connector.